# If a champion gets temporary bonus HP through ability (e.g. Lulu Ultimate) - which HP will drain first?

Tags: league-of-legends

When a champion gets temporary extra HP (not shield) through an ability (e.g. Lulu's ultimate) and he then takes damage, which HP are drained first?

A little example would be -> Champ has 1.500 HP, gets ulted by Lulu adds 300 Bonus HP.
Now he has 1.800 HP and gets damaged for 200 HP. After Lulu ult wearing of, does he again have 1.500 HP or will he have 1.300 HP (meaning the dmg was not "buffered" by the bonus HP).

Comment: Closers: This is not a duplicate. The other question asks about shields, whereas this question asks about bonus HP -- they're two entirely different mechanics. (Too bad I can't vote to reopen...)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Bonus HP acts exactly like regular HP. It is subject to the same damage reduction/amplification from resists. In addition, it is added to both your current and maximum health, but the additional max HP is only temporary.

At the expiration of the spell, any bonus HP you received will stay. The exception to this is if your current HP would be greater than your regular, unbuffed max HP. If this is the case, your HP will be reduced to your max HP.

For example, if you're at 400/1500 HP and you get Wild Growth'd for 300 HP, you'll be at 700/1800. If you proceed not to take any damage, you will be at about 700/1500 at the end of the 7 seconds.

However, if you're at 1500/1500 HP and you get Wild Growth'd for 300 HP, you'll be at 1800/1800. Suppose you take 200 HP of damage. This time, when the spell expires, you'll lose your extra HP. The 1600/1800 HP you have just before the ult wears off will become 1500/1500, since you cannot have more current HP than maximum HP.

One thing to note, by the way, is that all the current sources of bonus HP actually increase your maximum health (temporarily), meaning that % max HP damage sources will do slightly more damage than if you had unbuffed health.

Comment: This didn't quite answer the question. The real question (poorly phrased) was, "If you have less than your *normal* max HP left when an effect that increases your max HP by X ends, do you lose X hp?"

Comment: @ObliviousSage I think I answered the question fine; I stated what happens and also provided examples. For your case, I provided the example that 700/2800 will still be 700/2500, thought I didn't _explicitly_ state that it would be at the end of the spell; I thought the word "remain" was obvious enough. I'll add that right now, though, if it'll make you happy.

Comment: I think the question was answered in a roundabout way. A simpler answer would be "the temporary gain is to your max, not current, HP. In your example, after the buff you would end up with 1600 or your max HP, whichever is lower."

Comment: @MagRoader Yeah, I definitely could've been more to the point. The fourth paragraph more or less summarises this though.